System Manager Parameter Store Input
How can I pass the name of a Parameter Store's parameter name and value so that a step function updates it?
Input: parameter-store-Parameter-Name = "foo", value = "bar". Step function runs, updates the parameter store's "foo" parameter with the value "bar"

{
  "StartAt": "PutParameter",
  "States": {
    "PutParameter": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "Name-of-Parameter",
        "Value": "Value"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ssm:putParameter",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}


You execute a Step Function with a parameter in the form of JSON. If that JSON contains keys ParamKey and ParamValue like this:
{
    "ParamKey": "foo",
    "ParamValue": "bar"
}

Then you could update your Step Function to access the Input path:
{
  "StartAt": "PutParameter",
  "States": {
    "PutParameter": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name.$": "$.ParamKey",
        "Value.$": "$.ParamValue"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ssm:putParameter",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}


Works perfectly. Thank you
